# "Too many symbol files" after successfully submitting my apps

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcodebuild, app-store-connect

I downloaded Xcode 6 GM and submitted two Swift apps to the app store today.  Both passed all pre-upload verification and all the other stuff they had to pass and were successfully submitted.  But then I got two emails from Apple... one for each program and they both said this:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "xxxxxxxx" (my app name removed). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary [1431D977-72BC-308F-AB71-71529F25400B.symbols, 158C72A7-98AC-3F07-B2BE-88427591B413.symbols, 44973EAC-563E-340C-B549-55A5014A68BA.symbols, 678BF06F-0C3D-3A09-BFBF-699C7079FECD.symbols, 90907DDB-0400-38ED-BB5F-0C12333C0624.symbols, 93B79949-5757-374A-97B9-825AE1A61B7D.symbols, ABA05220-4FB0-397F-AFBB-08774A82F4CA.symbols, AD70F02A-4422-32B8-8C40-CF9B45A2CCC6.symbols, B0CC9F7D-C542-3E18-A518-B28B7ECABE80.symbols, BF6A4C3B-6FA5-3C51-8404-19C2F132458D.symbols, C9D6E078-8E2A-39D9-8DEE-476916A69CEE.symbols, CF5320DF-AB31-3845-BAD5-F6E51045D396.symbols, D4967AA3-8FB0-3712-B0DE-7F4144AF8F4B.symbols, D813B314-AD37-31D4-B675-442052994495.symbols, DF42A13F-08D8-3E71-B221-FC357E0B60F5.symbols, F5F636C2-F0E0-3CA7-8F7D-C49A36CD5C65.symbols]
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I'm going to guess that really has nothing to do with me or my apps... and it is just a quirk of day one Swift app submissions?  Both apps are still sitting in "Waiting for approval" mode.  I certainly can't think of anything I could change to make what they said go away!  Anyone else submit a Swift app yet and get that response?  Think I should just ignore it and wait to see what happens?

Comment: Mine said that and `Invalid Swift Support`. Any idea why I might get this? I'm using the latest Xcode.

Comment: same issue here, and my app can not submit for review.because of this issue.anyone solved?

Comment: same issue here. submitted for review anyway.. let's see what happens :)

Comment: Both of my Swift Apps were just approved to the App Store... so I guess I worried for nothing!  Whew...    :)

Answer (score 134):

This happens if you are including debug information of your libraries with the project archive but are not including binaries.

1. Open the Organizer window in Xcode
2. Right-click on an archive that had this issue and select "Show in Finder".
3. Right-click on the archive file and select "Show Package Contents"
4. In the "dSYMs" folder you will see several files. If you run the [`dwarfdump` console command](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dwarfdump/) on these files you will get a list of UUID strings:

   ```
   dwarfdump -u MyFile.dSYM
   ```

I'm sure you will find some matching UUIDs from Apple's email.

To avoid this warning you need to include with your archive only the `dSYM` files of your application and not the libraries. For this you need to change the build configuration of the libraries to not generate a `dSYM` file. Just search for "debug information format" in configuration and change it from `DWARF with dSYM File` to `DWARF` only.

For example, in the screenshot below you will find the Stripe iOS framework.

[image: Xcode project settings screenshot]

Comment: `dwarfdump -u *` in the folder to see all UUIDs

Comment: @Jon ooooh why i see it after i made one by one? :) anyway thanks!

Comment: Will removing the dSYM files means any crashes related to 3rd parties will not be symbolicated anymore on Crashlytics (or any other crash reporting tool)?

Comment: If you use firebase \ fabric, however, the dsym files should be used to view the crash logs on the site. Do they still work with this change?

Answer (score 93):

If you encountered this problem while using CocoaPods, add this to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
        end
    end
end
```

It will set Debug Information Format to DWARF only for all your Pod targets only (not the main app target)

Comment: @wzbozon Yes, I ask just to double check. Because after I did it, Crashlyticts stop working. Thanks!

Comment: Crashlytics should continue working for your app as this script changes build settings for pods only.

Comment: I agree. But you won't see reports for pods. One could also set DWARF with dSYM File for some pods only, for example development pods.

Comment: @Stan are you saying that Crashlytics will keep working? Cesar Rodriguez seems be saying it will not work.

Comment: This solved it for me. Don't forget to ```pod install```

Comment: Works for me. No such issue after uploading packages.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using CocoaPods and your app is set to use arm64 only (i.e. there is only arm64 in your project's info.plist)

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
</array>
```

then you can try adding the following script in your Podfile to solve this issue.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'arm64'
    end
  end
end
```

AND

set all your projects' targets (not the targets in Pods) to arm64 only

[image: Xcode project settings]

[CocoaPods Github issue reference](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7111)

Comment: Presumably you should include arm64e too now, no?

Comment: I'd include arm64s for the simulator. It'll be removed automatically for release builds.

Answer (score 14):

I have this issue due to the project has valid architecture **arm64** where the CocoaPods targets have valid architecture **arm64, armv7 and armv7s**.

To check which target has which valid architecture follow following steps

1. In Xcode -> Window -> Organizer
2. Select the archive and Reveal in Finder
3. On **.xcarchive** file, Show package content
4. Open terminal and give path of **dSYMs** folder.
5. Enter command `dwarfdump --uuid *` and it will show list of UUIDs with valid architectures.

The UUID will match with Apple's warning email

The main project and cocoa pods target suppose to have same valid architecture. By doing this, it will solve the issue.

Comment: I think it explains the best what is going on. I have these warnings only about libraries with armv7 architecture because my project is built only for arm64. Question remains if I should add armv7 to the project or remove it from Pods.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me by enabling bitcode - it was off before

**Enable Bitcode - Yes**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above helped troubleshoot, but couldn't solve.  We had project at iOS 12 but pods 10 - led to a bunch of armv7 files.  Updating pod to iOS 12 solved instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem fixed it by having the same "General" => "Deployment info" => "Deployment target" for all my targets.

Answer (score 0):

> In Xcode, look in Build Settings for “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy”
>   (COPY_PHASE_STRIP). When enabled, debug symbols are omitted from your
>   .app and placed into a .dSYM file. Otherwise your .app contains these
>   symbols. (By default, debug symbols are stripped from release builds
>   for reasons of obfuscation. You probably shouldn’t change this setting
>   for the release configuration.)

Make sure you check this option in project **Build Settings**

https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was a line in my `build.xcconfig` file. 
I had to remove

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0
```

which was setting the project to only build for arm64 (and not arm7). 
Following the steps by `@miOS` I could see that the pods project was building for both.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063850/3293172 iOS 11 dropped support for armv7 and armv7s so there is needed only arm64 if you have deployment target >= iOS 11.0.

Answer (score -3):

For me everything was very simple. I had the same problem and didn't know what to do for a week.

After you submit an archived application, you will see certificate for distribution in small popup window. There is a checkbox after it, which you should uncheck. After that you will submit it and get an email about symbol files. BUT it isn't problem. It's just a warning; not an error! If you uncheck that checkbox, your app will be sent correctly. I hope it may help you.

Screenshot of the checkbox and the popup:

[image: Screenshot of the checkbox and the popup]

Comment: I really hope you would be more detailed.... I have no idea what checkbox or popup you're talking about. Maybe a screen shot?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/6d7bb2035979cb75253ba92a40e8d898 I think I see it, it's this one

Comment: Yes, but this will strip all the symbols from the package, and therefore you won't receive symbolicated crash reports? (Do they even provide symbolicated crash reports in App Store apps now with TestFlight?)

Comment: This is not a valid solution to the problem. This is avoiding the symptom, not addressing the issue. See Mikhails answer for a description on how you are uploading symbols you don't need. This answer prevents uploading *any* symbols, thus breaking crash symbolication via iTunesConnect

Comment: DON'T do that, if you do you won't be able to analyze you app on App Store for crash errors