# "Too many symbol files" warning when submitting app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I submitted my app to the app store and received the following warning (not error):

> Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in
>   any binary [XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX.symbols,
>   XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX.symbols]

What caused this issue? How can I fix it? Will it create issues with crash reporting to Crashlytics?

Comment: are you check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25822290/3378413

Comment: Yes - unchecking the box where it say to send the symbol files is not a solution. I want to send the symbol files.

Comment: If you're using CocoaPods this is a known issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7111

Comment: Never use cocoapods

Answer (score 37):

Same problem occurred to me, and here is why this happening and the solution.

**Short version**: Redundant dSYM files are being produced due to improper project settings. In my case, the "project" consists of one major `.xcproject` and several CocoaPods projects, and the `Build Setting\Valid Architectures` setting of the latter one is more extensive than the former. Thus Xcode is producing redundant dSYM files for that pod projects and Apple detected those dSYM files is useless because the main project is set to a more constrained level.

**Bunch of bullshit version**:

Go to `Window`->`Organizer` and select your submitting version of archive and `right click`->`Show in finder` to locate that .xcarchive file. Then use `terminal` to navigate into the .xcarchive(it's a bundle like .app) and then to the `dSYMs` directory, run `dwarfdump --uuid *` to show the uuids of that dSYM files. Check whether the uuid(s) in the complaining email are in the list. The email says those dSYM files are redundant, so we should prevent producing them when building the archive.

For me, I used AFNetworking and other 3rd party frameworks in my app, and they are added to the project(or workspace more precisely) via CocoaPods. I need to guarantee my app won't be installed on any device older than iPhone5s, so I set `Valid Architectures` to `arm64` only in `Build Setting` of my project. In this case, I should also set `Valid Architectures` same for the `Pod` project targets(there may be several targets depending on how many frameworks you have added via Pods). By doing this, `Pods` project won't produce the redundant dSYM files during the build process. After all the `targets` are set properly, go to `Product`->`Archive` to re-archive. You should check the uuid(s) of dSYM files again just in case.

I hope I have myself understood :)

Comment: Right. I had this problem whenever I use Cocoapods subspec

Comment: If I will set Valid Architectures to arm64 it wouldn't run on iPad mini 3, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4,  iPhone 4S ?

Answer (score 12):

Let's say you are targeting iOS 11 but your cocoapods frameworks have minimum deployment target less that iOS 11, then add this at the end of your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer| 
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config| 
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
    end 
end
```

"Too many symbol files" warning is telling you that your project has more restrictive constraints than the cocopods frameworks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Crashlytics reporting will not be affected by this setting.

Comment: do you mean to say that doing the dump dwarf solution won't affect the crashlytics reporting on Fabric? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score -9):

Disable bitcode in the build setting.

I got similar problem and determined that enabling bitcode will produce BCSymbolMaps in the app archive.
Disabling bitcode resolve the issue.