# Too many symbol files

Tags: dart, flutter, app-store

When I upload IPA on app store, I get this error:

> Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary `[0B523B17-252B-35C1-A94E-EC1B5FE7AC6E.symbols, 1202FC31-64F7-35A5-A83A-BE08401F5617.symbols, 2CE5B047-5CDC-3C9B-B5FF-106501E63EB7.symbols, 2DF3956E-9B95-398E-9A4C-19CDF609E899.symbols, 6D4E71D5-9B85-3D1F-9E36-ADF9C56BC827.symbols]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755240/too-many-symbol-files-after-successfully-submitting-my-apps

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that this issue happens when you are including debug information of your libraries with the project archive but are not including binaries as stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755240/too-many-symbol-files-after-successfully-submitting-my-apps). Furthermore, a recent [blog](https://medium.com/@m.muizzsuddin_25037/itms-90381-too-many-symbol-files-bf9832d13ae7) featured the same issue:

> The issue came up because the application has disabled bitcode in the
> build setting, therefore libraries produced by CocoaPods doesn’t need
> to produce symbols for unused architecture. For instance arm7 for
> arm64 only apps.

Some steps you can follow to check which target has a valid architecture:

1. Open Xcode -> Window -> Organizer
2. Select the archive and Reveal in Finder
3. On ***.xcarchive*** file, Show package content
4. Open terminal and give path of **dSYMs** folder.
5. Enter command `dwarfdump --uuid *` and it will show list of UUIDs with valid architectures.

You will find the matching UUID's in the email you've received from Apple.

Try to check as well the existing GitHub issues related:

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7111
- https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-iOS/issues/188
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59237
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9664

To dig deeper into your issue, its good to provide more details like output of your `flutter doctor -v` and more context describing how you end up with this issue.